# Woocommerce - How to count a value from a specific attribute for all products?

Tags: wordpress, count, attributes, display

my question is how to count a value from a specific attribute for all products and display that result on my wordpress site? this value "number of parts" is an attribute (pa_bausteine) in every product in my shop. How can I count all the values ​​for the "number of parts" attribute and output them as one result?

for example: today we have a total of "number of parts" in our database.

many thanks for the help.
rené

Answer (score 0):

With SQL, you can !

```
global $wpdb;
$all_value = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'attribute_pa_bausteine')");
$total = 0;
foreach ($all_value as $value) {
    $total += $value->meta_value;
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($total);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

Ps: You have to test the format of the data you are recovering;)

Comment: Hi @Sco, thanks for your reply!
I have copied the first part of your code into the function.php and the 2nd part into a widget. unfortunately it doesn't work, it shows only the 'code' from part 2 in a strange way. It's probably not that difficult, but I don't do something like this every day. that's probably what you meant with the 'test the format'. Any hints for me, how i can do that? Thanks!!!